# How to add columns to a big numpy matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, scipy

I happen to have a `2-D` `NumPy` array of the form:

```
2 3
1 2
3 9 
.
.
.
```

I need to add another column to it so that it represents the `squared sum` of the first two columns like:

```
2 3 13
1 2 5
3 9 36
. 
.
.
```

What `NumPy` functions should I use to add this third column? My arrays have a large number of rows and I want to do it without using a `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the sum of square firstly, then use `numpy.column_stack` to bind it with the original array:

```
a = np.array([[2,3], [1,2], [3,9]])

np.column_stack((a, np.sum(np.power(a, 2), axis=1)))
#array([[ 2,  3, 13],
#       [ 1,  2,  5],
#       [ 3,  9, 90]])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [273]: x=np.array([[2,3],[1,2],[3,9]])
In [274]: x**2
Out[274]: 
array([[ 4,  9],
       [ 1,  4],
       [ 9, 81]], dtype=int32)
```

`keepdims` performs the sum while retaining a 2d shape

```
In [275]: (x**2).sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
Out[275]: 
array([[13],
       [ 5],
       [90]], dtype=int32)
```

Then a straight forward concatenate is possible:

```
In [276]: np.concatenate((x,_),axis=1)
Out[276]: 
array([[ 2,  3, 13],
       [ 1,  2,  5],
       [ 3,  9, 90]])
```

`reshape` and `hstack` and `column_stack` do the same sort of thing, just different ways of creating the column array for concatenate.

Comment: True, but I didn't see the other answer when I posted mine. Guess it can't be helped though, those few seconds can be the difference between 2 votes, and no votes.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I was just pointing out the commonality of our answers, with no implications about priority or votes.

Comment: Ah, alright. I might've read too much into your statement. It's a bit crushing when that happens - there's litte difference between the two answers but only one is recognised. Anyway, I upvoted you, so good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Its just simple, slice the first and second column and find the sum of squares and concatenate to its original numpy matrix.

Just one line.

```
       np.concatenate((x,np.array([x[:,0]**2 + x[:,-1]**2]).T),axis=1)
```

Comment: The other answers can also be reduced to one line, but there's no need to. Your answer is not better, if at all, it is worse because it cannot generalise to multiple columns.

Comment: Of course it is generalised as in the case he said.You can try it by adding more rows which may be the thing you're saying.